# Do I have to input a tensor into tf.nn.softmax?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

Why I can put a list into `tf.nn.softmax()`?

I checked the tensorflow guide. It shows that only non-empty tensor can be accepted for `tf.nn.softmax()`. Thanks.

```
customized_softplus = keras.layers.Lambda (lambda x : tf.nn.softplus(x))
print(customized_softplus([-10.,-5.,0.,5.,10.]))
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([4.5417706e-05 6.7153489e-03 6.9314718e-01 5.0067153e+00 1.0000046e+01], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: What version of Tensorflow are you using?

Comment: tensorflow 2.0.0